# How do I know if Grails domain POJO was changed since its retrieval?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am patching a domain object in my code. At the end, I need to save the object but only if it has been actually changed. Is it possible to avoid custom boolean flags having code like that?

```
User user = User.find(...)
if(maybe)
  user.name = "John"
if(user.changed())
  user.save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [isDirty](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/isDirty.html) to make this check.

```
if(user.isDirty() && user.save()) {
  // user saved successfully
}
```